# relatedTarget no funciona en select e input tipo date

Tags: html, jquery, input, html-select

Tengo un botón donde obtengo la información de Clientes para luego en un Modal, poder editarlos.

```
<button class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalClientesEdit" 
 data-clienteid="3082" 
 data-nombre="Chayane" 
 data-rfc="12344562312321" 
 data-razon="Chayane Inc" 
 data-sector="Musical" 
 data-poliza="póliza de prueba 2" 
 data-fecha="07/02/2023 12:00:00 a. m.">
Editar Modal
</button>
```

pero al momento de mostrar la información dentro del modal en los campos, en el campo de Póliza y Fecha no me muestra los datos y en los demás si.

```
$('#modalClientesEdit').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

    $("#frmClienteEdit input[name=ClienteId]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('clienteid'));
    $("#frmClienteEdit input[name=Nombre]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('nombre'));
    $("#frmClienteEdit input[name=Rfc]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('rfc'));
    $("#frmClienteEdit input[name=RazonSocial]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('razon'));
    $("#frmClienteEdit input[name=Sector]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('sector'));
    $("#frmClienteEdit select[name=PolizaId]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('poliza'));
    $("#frmClienteEdit input[name=FechaInicioPoliza]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('fecha').substring(0, 10));

});
```

```
<form action="/" id="frmClienteEdit" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="v7gO9Q-sOwroz89KjrB9B0fRdddOwst7EcmEKK5QIiEtwrE11pk5RwOTFysanDtQtsFYxsGzOkykj9Jugfhm6t10GMz27_cbXz7P5-3Tw-oEYGVWEoO10t5oatE-zQgxzlzMTtWlhqNbP21ahUny5A2">    
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-primary">
                <div class="card-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Editar Cliente</h3>
                </div>
                
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <hr>
                        
                        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="El campo Cliente debe ser un número." data-val-required="El campo Cliente es obligatorio." id="ClienteId" name="ClienteId" type="hidden" value="3082">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="Nombre">Cliente</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="El campo Cliente debe ser un tipo de cadena o matriz con una longitud máxima de '50'." data-val-maxlength-max="50" data-val-required="El campo Cliente es obligatorio." id="Nombre" name="Nombre" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Nombre" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="Rfc">RFC</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="El campo RFC debe ser un tipo de cadena o matriz con una longitud máxima de '15'." data-val-maxlength-max="15" data-val-minlength="El campo RFC debe ser un tipo de cadena o matriz con una longitud mínima de '12'." data-val-minlength-min="12" data-val-required="El campo RFC es obligatorio." id="Rfc" name="Rfc" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Rfc" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="RazonSocial">Razón Social</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="El campo Razón Social debe ser un tipo de cadena o matriz con una longitud máxima de '100'." data-val-maxlength-max="100" data-val-required="El campo Razón Social es obligatorio." id="RazonSocial" name="RazonSocial" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RazonSocial" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="Sector">Sector</label>
                        <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="El campo Sector debe ser un tipo de cadena o matriz con una longitud máxima de '30'." data-val-maxlength-max="30" data-val-required="El campo Sector es obligatorio." id="Sector" name="Sector" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Sector" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="PolizaId">Póliza</label>

                            <select class="form-control" id="PolizaId" name="PolizaId"><option value="1">Sin Póliza</option>
                             <option value="2">8X5 Seguridad Redes</option>
                             <option value="3">8X5 Servidores</option>
                             <option value="4">8X5 Servicios Administrados</option>
                             <option value="6">póliza de prueba 2</option>
                             <option value="7">8x5,FW,AP,SW,AD,WSUS,365</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="PolizaId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="FechaInicioPoliza">Fecha Inicio Póliza</label>

                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="El campo Fecha Inicio Póliza debe ser una fecha." id="FechaInicioPoliza" name="FechaInicioPoliza" type="date" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="FechaInicioPoliza" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="../Index">Cancelar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Esto es lo que utilizo para mostrar la información dentro del modal. Al momento de que me abre el modal, me muestra los datos en los input. También ya verifique que coincida con el nombre de los input. Cabe resaltar que el input de Poliza es un `select` y el de fecha un input de tipo `Date`

Comment: Coloca el html del form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Para seleccionar un `select` con jQuery tienes que buscar el `option` que está dentro, para eso tienes que recorrer la lista de options y buscar el correcto

```
$("#frmClienteEdit select[name=PolizaId] >  option").each((a,b)=> {
  if($(b).text() == $(e.relatedTarget).data('poliza')){    
     b.selected=true;
  }
});
```

1.- Para colocar una fecha en un `input date` el formato es `yyyy-MM-dd`, yo voy a suponer que tú lo tienes en español, es decir `dd/MM/yyyy`, entonces necesitamos dar vuelta el string y cambiar los `/` por `-`

```
const d= $(e.relatedTarget).data('fecha').substring(0, 10).split("/").reverse().join("-");
```

Demo:

```js
function ponerdatos(btn){
let e ={relatedTarget : btn}; //solo para testing

$("#frmClienteEdit input[name=ClienteId]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('clienteid'));

$("#frmClienteEdit input[name=Nombre]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('nombre'));

$("#frmClienteEdit input[name=Rfc]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('rfc'));

$("#frmClienteEdit input[name=RazonSocial]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('razon'));

$("#frmClienteEdit input[name=Sector]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('sector'));

$("#frmClienteEdit select[name=PolizaId] >  option").each((a,b)=> {
 if($(b).text() == $(e.relatedTarget).data('poliza')){    b.selected=true;
 }
});

const d= $(e.relatedTarget).data('fecha').substring(0, 10).split("/").reverse().join("-");
$("#frmClienteEdit input[name=FechaInicioPoliza]").val(d);



}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="dropdown-item" onclick="ponerdatos(this)"
 data-clienteid="3082" 
 data-nombre="Chayane" 
 data-rfc="12344562312321" 
 data-razon="Chayane Inc" 
 data-sector="Musical" 
 data-poliza="póliza de prueba 2" 
 data-fecha="07/02/2023 12:00:00 a. m.">
Poner datos
</button>

<form action="/" id="frmClienteEdit" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">


<input data-val="true" data-val-number="El campo Cliente debe ser un número." data-val-required="El campo Cliente es obligatorio." id="ClienteId" name="ClienteId" type="hidden" value="3082">

<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="El campo Cliente debe ser un tipo de cadena o matriz con una longitud máxima de '50'." data-val-maxlength-max="50" data-val-required="El campo Cliente es obligatorio." id="Nombre" name="Nombre" type="text" value="">

<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="El campo RFC debe ser un tipo de cadena o matriz con una longitud máxima de '15'." data-val-maxlength-max="15" data-val-minlength="El campo RFC debe ser un tipo de cadena o matriz con una longitud mínima de '12'." data-val-minlength-min="12" data-val-required="El campo RFC es obligatorio." id="Rfc" name="Rfc" type="text" value="">

<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="El campo Razón Social debe ser un tipo de cadena o matriz con una longitud máxima de '100'." data-val-maxlength-max="100" data-val-required="El campo Razón Social es obligatorio." id="RazonSocial" name="RazonSocial" type="text" value="">
                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="RazonSocial" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="El campo Sector debe ser un tipo de cadena o matriz con una longitud máxima de '30'." data-val-maxlength-max="30" data-val-required="El campo Sector es obligatorio." id="Sector" name="Sector" type="text" value="">

<select class="form-control" id="PolizaId" name="PolizaId"><option value="1">Sin Póliza</option>
<option value="2">8X5 Seguridad Redes</option>
<option value="3">8X5 Servidores</option>
<option value="4">8X5 Servicios Administrados</option>
<option value="6">póliza de prueba 2</option>
<option value="7">8x5,FW,AP,SW,AD,WSUS,365</option>
</select>

<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="El campo Fecha Inicio Póliza debe ser una fecha." id="FechaInicioPoliza" name="FechaInicioPoliza" type="date" value="">

</form>
```

Comment: Una duda más...  tengo en otra parte otro modal para mostrar datos al editar datos de un form pero utilizo el mismo jquery  para mostrar los datos en un select          `$("#frmEditarAgente select[name=ServicioNivelId]").val($(e.relatedTarget).data('servicionivelid'));` que si me funciona... por qué esta vez no? Y tengo el mismo form con el mismo `select`

Comment: @Luis En los `option` tienes 2 elementos el `value` y el texto, en tu caso era `póliza de prueba 2` cuyo value es `6`, pero tú le estas entregando el texto, entonces la única posibilidad es la que te digo yo. En cambio, seguro que en el otro caso estas enviando el `value`.  En otras palabras `$("select").val(algo)` sirve si ese "algo" es algún `value` existente de los options, el texto no sirve